# Creating boundaries from points and area measurements

Tags: qgis, gdal

I have a list of villages and the area measurement for each village. Is there a way to draw hypothetical boundaries of each village based on the area measurements and the calculation is able to measure around two thousand different villages?

Comment: (1) _"hypothetical boundaries"_ : definition ?
(2) _"and the calculation is able to measure around two thousand different villages"_ : what do u mean ?

Comment: I think to weighted Voronoi diagrams methods can help you
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weighted_Voronoi_diagram
http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/WeightedVoronoiDiagrams/

Answer (score 1):

**Create circular buffers with the specified area around each point.**

1. Use geometry and algebra to calculate the necessary radius from the given area value. We know that the `area of a circle = pi * radius^2`, so we can figure out that the `radius of a circle = squareroot(area/pi)`.

   Use the Field Calculator to add a field called "radius" using this formula:

   ```
    sqrt( "area"/ pi() )
   ```
2. Make sure your point layer is in a good CRS for calculating area and distance, IE not a geographic/unprojected WGS84 or Web PseudoMercator. If you're not sure what would be an appropriate CRS, have a look at the GIS recommendations of the local or country government for the area where the data is. If the points cover a very large area (eg many countries, multiple time zones, etc) it might be necessary to split them into several regional files, but this will also depend on how precise you want the circles to be.
3. In the Buffer tool, use the "radius" field as the Distance value.

   [image]

   Or, if you don't need a separate file and just want to *see* the circles on a map, use 2 times the "radius" field for the point symbol size (use map units for the symbol size units).

   [image]

Comment: @mhshaaban : Did that answer your question ?